# Media Library "HTTP error" when upload finishes

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I host multiple Wordpress sites on a single Ubuntu VPS. One of my sites just recently started giving me an "HTTP error" when uploading files to the media library.

I know this is a common error, but my error happens AFTER the file finishes uploading, and I can see the it there on the server, and that it's the correct size but it's corrupted and won't open. I'm thinking if it was a permissions issue then the file wouldn't be there at all, and the other sites on this server work fine.

I've already checked all the configs for nginx, php, and wordpress for file upload size limits and they all seem good. I never added any new plugins recently.

Comment: can you specify the exact error?

Comment: @karansharma Look it up, the error literally just says "HTTP error" from a wordpress notification. From my research it's an infamously vague error that can mean a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0):

Its the permissions problem, Please set 777 for uploads folder

then the HTTP "Error wont" appear

Comment: I don't think that's necessary, I have it on 755 for all my sites and they all work fine except for this one. If it were a permissions issue then Wordpress wouldn't be able to write to the folder at all. The file does get uploaded but somehow gets corrupted after it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically due to permission only, your Upload folder doesn't have correct permission.

Put this script file in your Wordpress root dir and execute it.( it will set the permission for all the folders and files)

**fix-wordpress-permissions.sh**

```
WP_OWNER=www-data # <-- wordpress owner
WP_GROUP=www-data # <-- wordpress group
WP_ROOT=$1 # <-- wordpress root directory
WS_GROUP=www-data # <-- webserver group

# reset to safe defaults
find ${WP_ROOT} -exec chown ${WP_OWNER}:${WP_GROUP} {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT} -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT} -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

# allow wordpress to manage wp-config.php (but prevent world access)
chgrp ${WS_GROUP} ${WP_ROOT}/wp-config.php
chmod 660 ${WP_ROOT}/wp-config.php

# allow wordpress to manage wp-content
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -exec chgrp ${WS_GROUP} {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced it's a permissions error.  You said it "used to work," so that makes me think it's something else.  Here's something you could try.

WordPress runs on PHP which uses two modules to handle images. These modules are called GD Library and Imagick. WordPress may use either one of them depending on which one is available.

Imagick, the default, is known to often run into memory issues causing the http error during image uploads. To fix this, you can change the default image editor to the GD Library by adding this function to your theme's `functions.php` file or, better, as a custom plugin.

```
// Change Default Image Editor Library Used by WordPress
function xyz_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
    $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';
    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );
    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'xyz_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
```

Picked up that little trick from WP Beginner: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-http-image-upload-error-in-wordpress/ (credit where credit is due).